# How to correct ‘One to Many table’ with missing references in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

I have a large datafile featuring a unique 11-digit reference on the first record of each related subset, but not on the subsequent records belonging to the same subsets, which instead feature a bogus 1 or 2-digit reference.   The table is in the order it was originally created in, so the subsets are still correctly grouped together, and the field comprising these references is called ‘Old Ref’.  I’ve just created a new field, called ‘New Ref’, which I want to populate with all the appropriate 11-digit references for each subset. How can this best be achieved in a script I can run on PL/pgSQL?

Here's an example of the data as is (current), and as I would like it to be updated:

```
   Current datafile
__________________________________
ID  | Old Ref       | New Ref
==================================
1   | 14740807000   |
2   | 1             |    
3   | 2             |    
4   | 3             |
5   | 58            |
6   | 14735113000   | 
7   | 1             |               
8   | 2             |    
9   | 39            |   
10  | 4             |    
11  | 5             |    
12  | 14915146000   | 
13  | 9             |        
14  | 27            | 
15  | 14915146000   | 
16  | 3             | 
17  | 4             |    
==================================

Sought updated datafile
__________________________________
ID  | Old Ref       | New Ref
==================================
1   | 14740807000   | 14740807000
2   | 1             | 14740807000    
3   | 2             | 14740807000    
4   | 3             | 14740807000 
5   | 58            | 14740807000
6   | 14735113000   | 14735113000 
7   | 1             | 14735113000               
8   | 2             | 14735113000    
9   | 39            | 14735113000    
10  | 4             | 14735113000    
11  | 5             | 14735113000    
12  | 14915146000   | 14915146000
13  | 9             | 14915146000        
14  | 27            | 14915146000
15  | 14915175959   | 14915175959
16  | 3             | 14915175959
17  | 4             | 14915175959    
==================================
```

I had what I thought was a neat way of doing this in MS Access, but that can’t handle the size of the datafile I need to update, which is one of the reasons why I’ve switched to PostgreSQL.

Here’s that MS Access script:

```
Sub UpdateRef()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim strSQL, Var1 As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT test.* FROM test", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rs.MoveFirst
Var1 = rs![Old ref]
rs![New Ref] = Var1
rs.Update

Do Until rs.EOF
  'SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, n
  If len(rs![Old ref]) > 2 Then
    Var1 = rs![field2]
  End If
rs![New Ref] = Var1
rs.Update
rs.MoveNext
Loop
  rs.Close
ExitSub:
  Set rs = Nothing
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've now included this.

Comment: What is the data type of `Old Ref`?

Comment: (Upvoted for responding promptly to a request for clarification - good work!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this `update` statement:

```
update test t
set newref = (select tt.oldref from test tt where tt.id = (
  select max(id) from test where id <= t.id and length(oldref) = 11
));
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hEFLSWbMuuB7gdqiWxp7d2/0)
This:

```
select max(id) from test where id <= t.id and length(oldref) = 11
```

gets the `id` of the row containing the 11 digit `oldref`